# Why is mosaic of rasters big, black rectangle in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, mosaic

I downloaded [NED rasters from USGS](http://eros.usgs.gov/#/Find_Data/Products_and_Data_Available/NED), and I now want to mosaic all of the rasters into one. I used the [Mosaic to New Raster tool](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001700000098000000), but the output is a big, black rectangle. Am I missing something? I feel like I might be making a rookie mistake.

Comment: Maybe a case of [life](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_game_of_life) imitating [art](http://www.kazimir-malevich.org/Black-Square.html)?  What are the values of the pixels in the resulting mosaic?

Comment: Min of 201 and Max of 4122

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have not recalculated the statistics, you can do this by right clicking on the raster and selecting "Calculate Statistics"

Comment: I let Arc calculate statistics over night, and it crashed on me this morning. I'm thinking this is a mixture of the raster being too large, and my work laptop hating me. I'm going to try to mosaic fewer rasters.

Answer (score 4):

if you are using arcmap you can use the stretched values along a colormap setting. (similar in qgis)
[image: stretch]
this also allows you to change the stretch type and so doesn't require building statistics.
[image]

Answer (score 3):

I had that same problem earlier today, actually.

It could be because you put in the incorrect number of bands in the field of the dialogue box. You can check the number of bands in ArcCatalogue in your input rasters and then make sure to put it in there.

Comment: I put 1 for the number of bands (the same as the input). Is there anything else you can think of? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you try kenbuja's suggestion?

Comment: I'm trying kenbuja's suggestion right now. It's taking awhile, so I'm thinking I will probably find out tomorrow morning if it worked.